# swift Parameter is implicitly non-escaping

Tags: swift

[image]

```
func test(f: () -> ()) {
    let a = f
    let b: () -> () = f // error
    
    a()
    b()
}
```

The only difference between a and b is whether the type is specified or not.

But what is the reason for the error to be printed only in b?

Please explain the clear difference between a and b.

Comment: @MartinR  I added it.

Comment: The same observation was made [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/do-we-have-non-escaping-local-variable-type/50184) in the Swift forum. I cannot see a clear explanation in that thread, in particular since it is later stated that *“For local variables, non-contexted closures are escaping by default.”*

Comment: @MartinR Presumably the source of the difficulty is that the phrase `() -> ()` means two different things in the two different places where it is used in the example code. Darned confusing really.

Comment: @matt: Yes. I find it confusing that it means a non-escaping closure in the parameter list (which can be overridden with an annotation), an escaping closure in a local variable declaration (which can not be overridden), but even more confusing that the assignment `let a = f` *does* define a non-escaping local closure variable. Seems a bit of a language deficit to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is shown because 'b' and 'f' do have different signatures.

'b' is an escaping closure 'f' is not.

when doing:

```
let a = f
```

you are copying 'f'. The signature stays the same "nonescaping () -> ()".

Declaring a closure in function definition gives you implicit 'nonescaping' in body gives you implicit 'escaping'.

Decorating your closure in the header with @escaping will solve the problem.

```
func test(f: @escaping () -> ()) {
```

If you want to know more:
https://medium.com/swiftcommmunity/what-do-mean-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-in-swift-d404d721f39d